# Transferring right join into subquery

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
select
    name, description 
from tblproducts
right join tblproductssales 
    on tblproducts.ID = tblproductssales.Product_ID
```

How can I get the same retreived data using subquery?

Comment: What is the issue with using JOINS?

Comment: What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: `select
    name, description 
from tblproducts where ID In (select Product_ID from tblproductssales)`

Comment: Thank you so much,I have already created this query,but it is not retrieving the same count of rows as the inner join.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
   (SELECT name FROM tblproducts WHERE ID = A.ProductID) AS name,
   (SELECT description FROM tblproducts WHERE ID = A.ProductID) AS description
FROM tblproductssales A
```

Comment: Thank you so much http://stackoverflow.com/users/2254931/nguy%e1%bb%85n-h%e1%ba%a3i-tri%e1%bb%81u) it is working ,thank you for your feedback

Comment: Can I talk your email or any contact information,in case any help needed.

Comment: My pleasure! Mail email: nguyenhaitrieuga@gmail.com or percy.nguyen@nexcel.vn

Comment: Thank you,just remember my name amr hassan from Egypt,my email is (miroooo37@gmail)

Comment: Yes, I'm from Vietnam

Comment: Oh I don't think that is a good practice, Nguyen. Also it's against the rules here to do that.

Comment: @Sorrel Vesper: Should you give Amr Hassan some suggested solutions?

Comment: I wasn't talking about the solution. You are not supposed to share personal information. Giving out such information is bad for your own self and also not allowed in here. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Right join to Subquery, I think It's right!
We could use cross apply (SQL 2005+)